# JS Loop - how do I loop through X items then wait for response to finish the loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to loop through X items but I want only to loop through only two of those items then wait for a response back from a function when its done then start another loop an so on. So, that only two loops only run at any given time until all items haven finished. What is he best efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: `for` loops won't wait. You'd have to create a function, use `setTimeouts` and so on.

Comment: can you show your code? and what kind of wait are you talking about? Is it ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is the single-threaded nature of javascript works to your advantage here.  The bad news is that if your work requires any form of asynchronous input, you'll have to A) write thread-blocking/locking code, or B) get creative with recursion and setTimeout.

The simpler solution (A) goes something like this. Let's assume you need to prompt the user every two loops to continue the operation.

```
for( var i=0, n=0; i < 10000; i++, n++ ){
  if ( n == 2 ) {
    /* Example of thread blocking operation
         "confirm" function blocks the thread, so
         the loop will stop executing until the user
         clicks "ok"
     */ 
    if ( !confirm("Keep looping?") ){
      break;
    };

    // Reset n so that it fires again in 2 iterations
    n = 0;
  }
}
```

Of course, if your work doesn't require asynchronous input from the user or an ajax call, all the better.

Fortunately, a more graceful solution is just around the corner.  The latest javascript spec (ES6) uses something called [generators](http://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators) to accomplish exactly what you're trying to do (you can think of them as an async-await).  Unfortunately, support for generators varies and is generally considered a more advanced topic, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Use promises.

Let's say you have a list of items to process. Create a function that takes an item off of the list, wraps it in a promise, initiates it, and then on resolution of the promise, invokes itself. Be sure to include logic to cleanly handle reaching the end of the list!

Call the function twice. You now have two execution pipelines running. Be aware that unless there's async processing going on, they're not really executing in parallel - remember we're single-threaded.

If the list is being added to WHILE items are being run, you're going to need some additional logic around restarting if something is added after it's been emptied.